# Does the Amazon SDK need to be installed on production server?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created an Amazon Web Services (AWS) console application on my local computer, after installing the .NET SDK. It works fine (and uses Amazon classes). So now I want to deploy the .exe file to a server. Do I also need to install the AWS SDK on the server for the program (.exe) to work properly? I'm assuming yes, but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to install it on the server as well; its just like any other library/dlls that your project may use.

Comment: Hi @E.J. Brennan, I thought so, just wasn't sure as I'm still sort of new to using SDKs. Is it any different installing it on the server with .NET framework versus a regular PC install? Thanks very much.

Comment: No, think of it as if your ec2 instance is just a plain vanilla server running whatever OS you chose. There is nothing special about it really.